# While loop shows only one row?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, dictionary, while-loop

```
<?php
    include 'db.php';   
    $sql_locations = "SELECT * FROM location";          
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_locations);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);      
    $markers = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))           
    {  

        $markers = array(       
        array(
        'abc',
        $row['latitude'],
        $row['longitude']
        ));     

    } ?>
```

this is my code for fetching location from database. and i have this below script for showing map.

```
<script>
function initialize() {
    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: "roadmap",
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(20.5937, 78.9629), // somewhere in the uk BEWARE center is required
        zoom: 1,
    };
    // Display a map on the page
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    map.setTilt(45);

    // Multiple Markers
    var markers = <?php echo json_encode( $markers );?>;



    // Display multiple markers on a map
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker, i;

    // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0]
        });

        // Allow each marker to have an info window
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }

    //Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function (event) {
        this.setZoom(5);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

my map is working fine. im just facing problem to display my all records from database. my while loop only shows first from table please help me with this.
i want to display all locations from database with their markers.on print_r o $markers it shows only first row of table. on var_dump on $rows it shows all data. but im getting only one marker for my first row. i have total 2 rows in my table. thanks in advance.

Comment: You overwrite your variable on each loop

Comment: `$markers[] = array('abc',$row['latitude'],$row['longitude']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You are overwriting your `$markers` variable in `while` loop. So you need to do like below:-***

```
$markers[] = array('abc',$row['latitude'],$row['longitude']);
```

***Or (if the outer array is required)***

```
$markers[] = array(array('abc',$row['latitude'],$row['longitude']));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are updating the whole array instead of adding an element to it.

change

```
   $markers = array(       
    array(
    'abc',
    $row['latitude'],
    $row['longitude']
    ));
```

to

```
 $markers[] = array(       
    array(
    'abc',
    $row['latitude'],
    $row['longitude']
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the variable `$markers` on each iteration.

You need to just add a new array element instead:

```
// Define the variable
$markers = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))           
{  
    // Push a new element to the array instead of overwrite it.
    $markers[] = array(
        'abc',
        $row['latitude'],
        $row['longitude']
    );     

}
```

Comment: If it worked, feel free to mark the question as solved